# Error During compilation of a C source code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I need help to identify the bug in my program that I have written in C. Please bear in mind that I am still learning C. I am trying to implement what I have learned to far. My IDE is MS visual studio 2010.

Here is the program, the program description is written as a comment:

```
/*The distance between two cities (in km) is input through the keyboard. 
Write a program to convert and print this distance in meters, feet, inches and centimeters*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

//I have used #include<stdio.h> and #include<conio.h> above


int main()
{
float km, m, cm, ft, inch ;

clrscr();
printf("\nEnter the distance in Kilometers:");
scanf("%f", &km );

// conversions

m=km*1000;
cm=m*100;
inch=cm/2.54;
ft=inch/12;

// displaying the results

printf("\nDistance in meters =%f", m);
printf("\nDistance in centimeters =%f", cm);
printf("\nDistance in feet =%f", ft);
printf("\nDistance in inches = %f", inch);

printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\nPress any key to exit the program.");
getchar();
return 0;
}

Errors:
1>e:\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\distance.cpp(32): error C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /YcStdAfx.h command-line option was not found in the source file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

error C2857: '#include' statement specified with the /YcStdAfx.h command-line option was not found in the source

This means the compiler (VisualStudio 2010) is forcing the inclusion of StdAfx.h but in the source you are not including it.

Try adding:

```
#include <StdAfx.h>
```

at the top of your source file.

Answer (score 3):

SanSS already explained the error message. Let me shortly explain the warnings. The first warning about scanf can be ignored at this point. The problem with scanf is that it is unsafe, if you try to read in a string into a pre-allocated C-string (e.g. a char array or char pointer). You are reading in a float, which always has a fixed size (usually four bytes). So no overflow can happen here.

The second warning is about the expression `inch=cm/2.54`. The literal 2.54 is treated as a double precision value. So `cm/2.54` will be a double value as well -- the result of such a computational expression will always be upcast. Although `cm` is of type `float` (single precision), the result will be a `double`. However, `inch` is of type float, so the assignment `=` will implicitly downcast the result from `double` to `float`. Since a `float` variable has less precision, the result will become less precise. To avoid this warning, change the numerical literal, so that the expression looks like this: `inch = cm / 2.54f`. This tells the compiler that 2.54 is to be treated as a single precision `float` literal.

Answer (score 3):

to warning `C4996`
at vs 2010, especially at vs 2012.
you have to put the the following code at the top of the file

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

And set the precompiled header option to "not using" at the project's property page.